# Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test with unequal samples

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I did a simulation and the outcome's size was almost 30k. The other sample I want to compare them has only 50. Can I still do the test or should I radnomly pick 50 from the first and do it?

Comment: Could you explain what might prevent you from doing this test with the two sample sizes you have?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47498/1352